# Why crna doesn't use the last versions of react and react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-native-app

In my package.json i have : 
"react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-native": "0.54.0"

Normally the current version of react is 16.3.0 without alpha and for react-native 0.55.0

Answer (score 0):

CRNA is a tool to make starting a new react-native project much quicker and easier. CRNA apps have dependencies on 3 projects. Those "puzzle pieces" all have to fit together very specifically for CRNA, expo, etc to work simply. Changes on one of the projects could potentially break an implementation from another as they are all separately owned and maintained. CRNA reports a map of dependency versions that are suited to work for each other at https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md